# Download artifacts archive from Artifactory

Tags: repository, artifactory

I'm testing Artifactory 4.2.0 PRO.

The really nice feature is the possibility to download an archive of all files produced by the build by executing, something like:

```
curl -XPOST -u admin:password -H "Content-Type: application/json"  http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/archive/buildArtifacts -d '
{
      "buildName": "Vehicle Routing Problem", 
      "buildNumber": "3", 
      "archiveType": "zip"
}' > build.zip
```

However, I'm unable to find if there is a possibility to do the same (download archive) when specifying exact properties using AQL. I have been trying to upload other artifacts with properties exactly the same as those pushed by the build, but they were not fetch by the snippet above (I assume some sort of metadata is stored somewhere).

What are the possibilities to fetch multiple artifacts without using many HTTP queries?

Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Retrieve Folder or Repository Archive API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveFolderorRepositoryArchive) allows to download an archive file (supports zip/tar/tar.gz/tgz) containing all the artifacts that reside under the specified path (folder or repository root). However it does not support filtering by properties.

The [Artifactory CLI](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-cli-go) supports concurrently downloading multiple files. It also supports downloading files we matches a set of property values. The CLI, however, will use multiple HTTP requests for doing so.

A third option would be developing a custom [user plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins) which allows downloading an archive of artifacts matching a set of properties. An execution user plugin can be [executed](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ExecutePluginCode) as a REST API call. There is a [sample plugin](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/download/downloadDirectoryContent) in the JFrogDev GitHub account which can serve as a good start point. This plugin allows downloading the content of a directory as an archive.

Comment: Custom user plugin is a great choice. Thanks