# Alternatives for downloading large repositories from jfrog artifactory using curl/REST api

Tags: jenkins, build, artifactory

What's the fastest/most efficient or commonly used method to download an archived/compressed version 100+ GB repo directory for a build in jenkins pipeline.

I'm a beginner and I only know that it's possible to curl via ?archiveType=zip as in [Download artifacts archive from Artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540960/download-artifacts-archive-from-artifactory)?

Or is it already a proper way to do it?

Comment: Which type of package (Maven , pypi, yum, nuget , npm, bower) did you publish your repo as?

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply and sorry for late answer. It was posted as a generic package type.

Answer (score 0):

[Jenkins Artifactory plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in) splits the downloaded files and download each part concurrently.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that, but could you elaborate a bit more, please?